# In JavaScript "strict mode" how to define variable only if it doesn't exist in global scope?

Tags: javascript

I use a variable called `DEBUG` in my code to conditionally collect debugging info:

```
if (DEBUG) console.log('...');
```

This variable may already be set somewhere else, for example I statically set it to false when I want to build for production (which effectively removes the entire line of code after optimizing the code).  However when it is not defined, in order to avoid undefined variable error, I set it to a default value:

```
if (typeof DEBUG === 'undefined') DEBUG = false;
```

The problem is that it doesn't work in `strict mode` because using global variable `DEBUG` is not allowed. If I change it to:

```
if (typeof DEBUG === 'undefined') var DEBUG = false;
```

then it [doesn't work](https://jsfiddle.net/ujtwt8g3/) as expected because of hoisting in JavaScript.

So my question is in "strict mode" how should I define a variable only if it doesn't exist in global?

---

Edit: `windows.DEBUG` is not helpful, because it only works in browser not in node.js (I need both of them) and also it doesn't allow me to use code optimizer to set global variable and remove debug lines (See: `global_defs` in UglifyJS doc).

Comment: Did you try defining it as a node global variable? Such as ``global.DEBUG``?

Comment: Use `global` to reference global variables: `if (typeof global.DEBUG === 'undefined') global.DEBUG = false;`. Other code can still reference via `DEBUG`.

Comment: I need to support all JS frameworks, and I want to be able to remove debug code with code optimizer, so <scope>.DEBUG doesn't work.

Comment: @AliShakiba - I give up on this question.  Every time we give you a solution, you add MORE requirements.  Not worth chasing our tails here.  Next time you post a question, please state ALL the requirements up front.  You can't define a global symbol `DEBUG` from a node.js module in strict mode without assigning `global.DEBUG`.   strict mode explicitly prevents the creation of accidental or non-explicit globals.

Comment: @jfriend00 Sorry for update, but I'm not adding requirement, this is just common case for js packages which are supposed to work in both browser and node.js.

Comment: From our point of view, you wrote a question.  I answered that question.  Then, several more times you added more constraints on the problem.  I answered the first several revisions of those constraints.  Now, I'm tired of chasing a moving target because you keep unpeeling more layers of the actual problem you're trying to solve and, in doing so, you're rejecting legit previous answers to what you had asked.  I hope you can at least understand how frustrating that is from our end.  I no longer feel like I understand the actual constraints of this question.

Comment: This now sounds the real question is how you get a specific tool to work with your code for removing DEBUG lines, but there's no detail in your question that actually asks that and lays out what is and isn't acceptable solutions and what the tool is expecting.

Comment: @jfriend00 Before you answer the question I had already mentioned code optimizer and node.js in question.  What I added after your answer was that I need both browser and node.js and I emphasized on code optimizer.

Comment: Well, there's no way in strict mode to create a global variable in node.js from a lower scope without using the `global` prefix.  So, if that's what you were asking, can't be done.  That's an explicitly designed feature of strict mode.  In the browser, you can actually use `var DEBUG` in the global scope, but not in node.js.  There are plenty of ways to deal with globals in a mixed environment (code that works in both browser and node.js), but it requires using your own global prefix that is set based on the environment.  You can read the value of a global without the prefix.

Comment: As I have said, you only have to **assign** to `global.DEBUG`. Everything else can still just **read** `DEBUG`. That should have no impact on minification. Or do you expect uglifyjs to remove `if (typeof DEBUG === 'undefined')` as well?

Comment: @FelixKling I just tested `window.DEBUG` and `global.DEBUG` with uglifyjs and `compress: {dead_code: true, global_defs: {DEBUG: false}},` it doesn't remove `if (DEBUG) {...}` code as dead code.

Comment: Maybe you are misunderstanding me. You still have to use `if (DEBUG)` for code removal to work. You should only use `global.debug` to **set** the value. How you set the value should not have any impact on the minifier.

Comment: @FelixKling Ah, I see, I was checking `global.DEBUG` instead of setting it.

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks, setting `global.DEBUG` instead of `DEBUG` works (however to let optimizer statically evaluate variables checking the variable should be the same: `typeof DEBUG === 'undefined'`).

Answer (score 4):

Your example:

```
if (typeof DEBUG === 'undefined') var DEBUG = false;
```

will work just fine.

You are correct to be thinking about hoisting, but it won't cause you a problem here because what this really looks like to the interpreter is this:

```
var DEBUG;
if (typeof DEBUG === 'undefined') DEBUG = false;
```

But, `var DEBUG` when `DEBUG` is already defined in this scope does nothing.  It doesn't affect a previously defined variable by the same name in this scope, it doesn't cause an error, it doesn't change the value of the `DEBUG` variable.  All it does is define it (if it isn't already defined in this scope).

Note: This is not the case for `const` or `let` which do not let you "redeclare" an existing variable in the same scope (they make that into an error).  You can only do this with `var`.

---

Your comments seem to indicate that you're trying to affect a global variable in node.js (even though your question says nothing about that).  Globals in node.js are referenced via the `global` object.  So, perhaps what you want is this:

```
if (typeof global.DEBUG === 'undefined') global.DEBUG = false;
```

In strict mode in node.js, there is no way to defined a global variable that does not use the `global` prefix.  This is because in strict mode, the only way to define a global variable without a prefix is to use `var` or `let` or `const` in the actual global scope, but in node.js everything is in a module scope so you can't put one of these declarations into the global scope.  So, in node.js, creating a global variable has to use the `global` prefix as in:

```
global.DEBUG = false;
```

You can, however test for a global variable that you know is already defined without using the prefix as long as you are sure there is no intervening variable of the same name defined in a closer scope (because if there is, you will be testing that closer defined variable, not the global one).

```
if (DEBUG) console.log("in debug mode");
```

This will work as long as `DEBUG` is defined already in some scope that is visible to this code.

What you can't do is:

```
if (DEBUG) console.log("in debug mode");
```

when DEBUG is not defined anywhere.  That will cause a Javascript error.  So, as long as you make sure that DEBUG is defined, then you can reference it without a prefix.

---

If you're looking for a browser/node.js way of referencing the global object that will work in either, see this: https://gist.github.com/rauschma/7960405

Comment: @AliShakiba - You put your statement inside a function.  That second `var` declares a new and different variable inside that function scope.  You have to do this in the SAME scope as the variable you're testing for.  And, your question didn't show anything about that situation.

Comment: Right, I'm using node, so each file has its own scope.

Comment: @AliShakiba - We're now covering stuff that is not in your question at all.  Your question appears to be asking about a variable in the SAME scope.  If you're asking about a global variable in node.js, then you must reference it specifically with `global.DEBUG` to make sure you're testing and initializing a global when you're in a node.js module.  `if (typeof global.DEBUG === 'undefined')  global.DEBUG = false;`.

Comment: @AliShakiba - I added some info about a global variable in node.js.

Comment: Setting `global.DEBUG` works, however to let optimizer statically evaluate variables `typeof global.DEBUG === 'undefined'` needs to be `typeof DEBUG === 'undefined'`.